# Owl Carousel Dots-Data

Tags: php, owl-carousel

I need to show the thumbnails in the owl carousel. I have seen there's a way to do it by setting dotsData: true in the settings and then adding the tag into the div item.

I am doing something wrong in the code but can not see it:

```
echo '<div class="item" data-dot="<img src="images/renders/img-' . $i . '.jpg">"><img src="images/renders/img-' . $i . '.jpg"></div>';
```

How can I write it properly?

Comment: I'm not sure this method works. but either way Need to escape the inner quotes into &quot; or \': 
`echo '<div class="item" data-dot="<img src=\'images/renders/img-' . $i . '.jpg\'>"><img src="images/renders/img-' . $i . '.jpg"></div>';`

Comment: Seems a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336303/owl-carousel2-set-dotsdata. And, this would maybe help: ```<?php
$img_src = "images/renders/img-$i.jpg"; ?>
<div class="item" data-dot="<img src='<?= $img_src ?>'>"><img src="<?= $img_src ?>"> </div>
<?php ?>```

Answer (score 0):

Image tag will not work. You must set button with background-image style:

```
echo '<div class="item" data-dot="<button style=\"background-image: url(images/renders/img-' . $i . '.jpg);\">03</button>">';
```

And via CSS set height, width, background-size etc. of the buttons.